# Delete unused attribute values

Tags: attributes, magento-1, import, eav

I am using the [fastsimpleimport](https://github.com/avstudnitz/AvS_FastSimpleImport) module to create my custom import. This has a `setDropdownAttributes()` function to automatically create needed attribute values but it does not remove unused values. Those still show up in my advanced search.

How can I search and remove unused attribute values?

I think they are stored in `eav_attribute_option_value` but I am not sure how to check if they are used by a product.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6863471/delete-all-unused-attribute-options

Answer (score 19, accepted):

LuFFy's answer is technically incorrect as it has 3 issues:

- it will remove values for `admin` store view only leaving some store-views related garbage
- it will remove unused values of attributes of all entity types
- it will remove **ALL** values from attributes with "multiple select" type regardless if they are assigned to any products or not because they options are stored in `catalog_product_entity_varchar` and not `catalog_product_entity_int`

The query below addresses these problems:

```
    DELETE o, v
      FROM `eav_attribute` a
INNER JOIN `eav_attribute_option` o ON a.`attribute_id` = o.`attribute_id`
INNER JOIN `eav_attribute_option_value` v ON v.`option_id` = o.`option_id`
INNER JOIN `eav_entity_type` t ON t.`entity_type_id` = a.`entity_type_id`
 LEFT JOIN `catalog_product_entity_int` pi ON o.`option_id` = pi.`value` AND o.`attribute_id` = pi.`attribute_id`
 LEFT JOIN `catalog_product_entity_varchar` pv ON o.`option_id` = pv.`value` AND o.`attribute_id` = pv.`attribute_id`
     WHERE pi.`entity_id` IS NULL
       AND pv.`entity_id` IS NULL
       AND t.`entity_type_code` = "catalog_product"
```

Comment: @tim-bezhashvyly This is a much better answer. However, this doesn't correctly match multiple-select attributes. If you change `ON o.option_id = pv.value` to `ON FIND_IN_SET(o.option_id, pv.value)` then this will correctly match multiple-select attributes.

Comment: Might I also suggest that you add `a.is_user_defined = 1` to your WHERE clause as well. You likely don't want to remove any attribute values from system attributes.

Comment: This doesn't work on multi-select

Answer (score 0):

```
delete c,b
from eav_attribute a
inner join eav_attribute_option b on a.attribute_id = b.attribute_id
inner join eav_attribute_option_value c on c.`option_id` = b.option_id
LEFT join catalog_product_entity_int pi on b.option_id=pi.value and pi.store_id=0 and b.attribute_id=pi.attribute_id
where entity_id is null
```

Try this Query..