# Delete Magento Attribute value

Tags: magento-1.7, product-attribute

I have some attribute with more that 300 values in Magento. I am trying to delete some, when I click delete the value does not show anymore so I save the attribute and the message "attribute saved" display but the value is still there when I check the attribute again. 
Any idea on how to solve this will be really helpful.

Thanks

Comment: Similar question http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/1110/delete-unused-attribute-values

Answer (score 1):

Add this in your magento root .htaccess file (in the end) and try again:

```
<IfModule mod_php5.c>
php_value max_input_vars 10000
php_value suhosin.post.max_vars 10000
php_value suhosin.request.max_vars 10000
</IfModule>
```

It increases the limit to POST input values to the server.

Comment: I do not have a .htaccess file in my Magento folder. I did a filter check using WinScp to check if the file was there after trying to find it manually and I could not find it.

Comment: it should be there, hidden.. if not, you can create one

Comment: I created one with the codes you suggested, but it still does not work. I am not sure that the .htaccess file that I created communicates with the other files. Is it something else you think I should add?

Comment: check what value for `max_input_vars` you have in php.ini file.. increase it to some bigger value (like 5000 or 10000), restart apache and see if that works.. i have strong feeling that is the issue.